# can we set a specific route to show insted of an dynamic route in nextjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am developing a nextjs project and I have a page that has dynamic routing, something like this :
`.../user/[id]/[another id]`

I want to set a unique route for every user. but assuming the nextjs default routing system, it seems I have to create a single page for every user.
I wonder if there is any way to set a specific route like '/john' for every user that represent the same page for the route: `.../user/[id]/[another id]`

can anyone help me with this?
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can just create a page in the `/pages` or `/src/pages` directory like this:

```
[user].js
```

then you can read this value in your component as :

```js
const UserComponent = ({user})=>{
    return <p>{user}</p>
}
UserComponent.getInitialProps = (ctx) => {
    return { user: ctx.query.user }
}
export default UserComponent;
```